# RewriteRule for a url link

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteRule    ^article/?$    weq_page.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "blog"
```

This rule works fine by replacing the actual page with **article** like this: **site.com/article** the page loads fine.
Then i wanted to display the actual article link; i wrote this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([\w-]+)$    weq_page.php?title=$1
```

Also this rule works fine. But there is a problem i found and is bothering me alot.

Take this example of the article title:
**site.com/article/Proposed-Argument-for-the-Treatment-of-Diabetics**
This link will load okay

BUT if the link has lets say: **site.com/article/Proposed-Argument-for-the-Treatment-of-Diabetics.**

This link will give me a ***page not found*** because the article title has a *full stop*(**.**) at the end.

Even if the title has:{**&,?,:,;,,**}, will give me a page not found.

Is there any way to write a rule that will allow all the above if available at any title, the web page loads okay?

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP?

Comment: Why do you limit the rewriting patten to certain characters `([\w-]+)` if you want to accept more characters?

Comment: @arkascha how? i need help for that

Comment: I suggest you read one of the millions of introductions to regular expressions and think about what that `([\w-]+)` actually means.

Comment: @arkascha, your push, has made me rectify the problem. Thanks. Everything works fine now

Comment: @dean That's great to hear. I suggest you write an answer to your question yourself. So that others can learn from your learnings. Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$    weq_page.php?title=$1` that's what i used to correct and make everything work fine.